# Computing the Fubini-Study metric in affine chart

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-space, kahler-manifolds

Someone asked this question recently and then deleted it, but I still would like to figure out the answer.

Let us try to compute the Fubini-Study metric in inhomogeneous coordinates on $\mathbb{C} P^n$,  using the Hopf fibration. For simplicity, let us do $n=1$.

Start with $\mathbb{C}^2$. In the standard coordinates $(Z_0, Z_1)$, the standard flat metric is given by $g= dZ_0\,d\overline{Z_0} + dZ_1\,d\overline{Z_1}$. This metric restricts to the round metric on the unit sphere $S^3$ seen as $S^3 = \{|Z_0|^2 + |Z_1|^2 = 1\}$.

The group of unit complex numbers $U(1)$ acts on $S^3$ by multiplication, and the quotient is the complex projective line $\mathbb{C}P^1$. (Note that this is the Hopf fibration $S^1 \to S^3 \to S^2$). In homogeneous coordinates $[Z_0 \colon Z_1]$ on $\mathbb{C}P^1$, the projection map $\pi \colon S^3 \to \mathbb{C}P^1$ is just $(Z_0, Z_1) \mapsto [Z_0 \colon Z_1]$. In the inhomogeneous coordinate $z = Z_1/Z_0$ (such that $[Z_0 \colon Z_1] = [1 \colon z]$), the projection map is $(Z_0, Z_1) \mapsto z = Z_1/Z_0$.

Since the metric on $S^3$ is invariant under the action of $U(1)$, it descends to a metric on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ such that the projection map $\pi \colon S^3 \to \mathbb{C}P^1$ is an isometry. This metric on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ is the Fubini-Study metric. In order to compute it, we can use any local section $s \colon \mathbb{C}P^1 \to S^3$, for instance:
$$s(z) = \left(Z_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z\overline{z}}}, Z_1 = \frac{z}{\sqrt{1+z\overline{z}}}\right)~.$$
The Fubini-Study metric in the coordinate $z$ will simply be given by the pull-back metric $g_{FS} := s^* g = dZ_0\,d\overline{Z_0} + dZ_1\,d\overline{Z_1}$ where $Z_0$ and $Z_1$ denote (somewhat abusively) the functions of $z$ given by the definition of $s(z)$ as above.

A direct computation gives:
$$dZ_0 = \frac{-\overline{z}\,dz - z\,d\overline{z}}{2(1+z\overline{z})^{3/2}}$$
$$dZ_1 = \frac{(2+z\overline{z})\,dz - z^2 \,d\overline{z}}{2(1+z\overline{z})^{3/2}}$$ 
which yields
$$dZ_0\,d\overline{Z_0} + dZ_1\,d\overline{Z_1} = \frac{-\overline{z}^2\,dz^2 - z^2\,d\overline{z}^2 + 2(2+z\overline{z})\,dz\,d\overline{z}}{4\,(1+z\overline{z})^2}$$

The problem is that this is not what is expected: instead we expect
$$g_{FS} = \frac{dz\,d\overline{z}}{(1+z\overline{z})^{2}}~.$$

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I found where I went wrong but it took me a while to fix it.

First of all notice that the claim that "the projection map $\pi \colon S^3 \to \mathbb{C}P^1$ is an isometry" cannot be true, since $S^3$ and $\mathbb{C}P^1$ do not have the same dimension. When one does a Riemannian quotient, what is required is that the projection map is isometric *for tangent vectors that are orthogonal to the fibers*. For this reason, it is also false to say that "in order to compute the metric on $\mathbb{C}P^1$, we can use any local section $s \colon \mathbb{C}P^1 \to S^3$". Only a section which is orthogonally transverse to the orbits of the $U(1)$-action will be isometric.

So in order to fix my calculation I looked for such an orthogonal section. Denote by $s_0 \colon \mathbb{C}P^1 \to S^3$ the section we chose originally, then let us look for another section of the form $s(z) = e^{i\theta(z)}\,s_0(z)$, where $\theta(z)$ is a real-valued unknown function to be determined so that $s(z)$ is orthogonal to the orbits of the $U(1)$-action. We can explicitely find the equation satisfied by $\theta$ by writing that $s_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)$ must be orthogonal (for the standard flat metric $g$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$) to the vector field $\vec U$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ generating the $U(1)$-action.

If my calculations are correct, with:
$$s_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right) = \frac{\partial Z_0}{\partial z} \frac{\partial}{\partial Z_0} + \frac{\partial (\overline{Z_0})}{\partial z} \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{Z_0}} + \frac{\partial Z_1}{\partial z} \frac{\partial}{\partial Z_1} + \frac{\partial (\overline{Z_1})}{\partial z} \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{Z_1}}$$
where I have written 
$$s(z) = \left(Z_0(z), Z_1(z)\right) = \left(\frac{e^{i\theta(z)}}{\sqrt{1+z\overline{z}}}, \frac{z\,e^{i\theta(z)}}{\sqrt{1+z\overline{z}}}\right)$$
and
$$\vec U = iZ_0 \frac{\partial}{\partial Z_0} -i\overline{Z_0} \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{Z_0}} + iZ_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial Z_1} +  -i\overline{Z_1}  \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{Z_1}}$$
we find:
$$g\left(s_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right), \vec U\right) = 2 \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z} -\frac{i\overline{z}}{1+z\overline{z}}$$
therefore we get the equation
$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z} = \frac{i\overline{z}}{2(1+z\overline{z})}~.$$

This is a very simple PDE on the function $\theta \colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$, unfortunately, it does not have any solutions! Indeed, the equality of the mixed second partial derivatives of $\theta$ is not verified, contradicting [Schwarz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27s_theorem). This was very troubling to me at first so I checked my computations again and again. But I am now inclined to think that the conclusion of all this is that *there does not exist such orthogonal sections*. It is maybe a bit counter-intuitive, but it is entirely possible that the distribution in the tangent space of $S^3$ defined as the orthogonal complement of $\vec U$ is not tangent to submanifolds, in other words is not integrable (i.e. stable under the Lie bracket, by the [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)#Formulation_using_vector_fields)). **If someone could please confirm this, that would be great**. Maybe there is a nice way to think about this geometrically in terms of the Hopf fibration (where the $U(1)$-orbits are Villarceau circles).

In any case, it is still possible of course to compute the quotient metric $g_{FS}$ on $\mathbb{C}P^1$. We're just going to have to work infinitesimally (in the tangent space) rather than with sections, which is actually easier. Let me do it for completeness:
Let $\vec v = \alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial z} + \beta \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}$ be a (complexified) tangent vector to $\mathbb{C}P^1$ at some point $z$, and let us look for the unique tangent vector $\vec V$ at the point $\left(Z_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z\overline{z}}}, Z_1 = \frac{z}{\sqrt{1+z\overline{z}}}\right)$ such that:

1. $\vec V$ is tangent to $S^3$ (i.e. orthogonal to the radial vector field $\vec R$).
2. $\vec V$ is orthogonal to $\vec U$ (the vector field generating the $U(1)$-action).
3. $\pi_* (\vec V) = \vec v$.

It is straightforward to find that $\vec V$ is given by:
$$\vec V = (1+z\overline{z})^{-3/2}\left(-\alpha \overline{z}\frac{\partial}{\partial Z_0} -\beta z \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{Z_0}} + \alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial Z_1} + \beta \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{Z_1}}\right)~.$$
Since $\pi$ must be isometric on $\vec V$, we can write:
$$g_{FS}(\vec v, \vec v) = g(\vec V, \vec V) = \frac{\alpha \beta}{(1 + z \overline{z})^2}$$
and we can finally conclude that $$g_{FS} = \frac{dz\, d\overline{z}}{(1 + z \overline{z})^2}~.$$

Comment: Regarding your request for confirmation, you're perfectly correct: The distribution of two-planes orthogonal to the Hopf fibres is a famous [contact structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_geometry) on $S^{3}$.

Comment: @Cedric $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are any two complex numbers, the components of $\vec{v}$ in the basis $(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}})$. Given such an arbitrary complefixied tangent vector $\vec{v}$ to $\mathbb{C}P^1$, I find the unique tangent vector $\vec{V}$ to $S^3$ such that 1.2.3. Since the projection is a Riemannian submersion, we conclude that $g_{FS}(\vec{v}, \vec{v}) = g(V, V)$. This is how we find the Fubini-Study metric.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have understood it already. However I am having issues with checking you third property. To do it we must check that if we reexpress the partial derivatives with respect to $Z_0$ and $Z_1$ in $\vec{V}$ in terms of $z$ and $\overline{z}$. then we get exactly $\vec{v}$ right?

Comment: Yes, you know that the projection is defined by $\pi(Z_0, Z_1) = Z_1/Z_0$, and you want to check that the differential of $\pi$ at $(Z_0, Z_1)$ sends $\vec{V}$ to $\vec{v}$.