# Fubini-Study metric of HP^n in affine coordinates

Tags: riemannian-geometry, projective-geometry, quaternions

I want to obtain the Fubini-Study metric of $\mathbb{H}P^n$ in affine coordinates, similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014659/computing-the-fubini-study-metric-in-affine-chart) but here of the quaternionic projective space.

1. How exactly is the Fubini-Study metric defined on $\mathbb{H}P^n$? Every literature I consult says: "We do it simlarly as in the complex case". What does that even mean?
2. How do we get the Fubini-Study metric in terms of affine coordinates, where $\mathbb{H}P^n$ is of course considered as a **real** manifold?

I appreciate both, literature and/or explaination which might help me to get on the right track. Thank you! :)